# For all pairs of reviewers such that both reviewers gave a rating to the same movie, return the names of both reviewers

Tags: sql, sqlite

Stanford Self Paced Course for SQL question:

> For all pairs of reviewers such that both reviewers gave a rating to
> the same movie, return the names of both reviewers. Eliminate
> duplicates, don't pair reviewers with themselves, and include each
> pair only once. For each pair, return the names in the pair in
> alphabetical order.

The schema :

```
Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
```

There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.

```
Reviewer ( rID, name )
```

The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.

```
Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )
```

The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.

My attempt:

```
Select R.Name, R2.Name 
From Reviewer R 
    Join Reviewer R2 on (R.rID = R2.rID)
    Join Rating Rt on (Rt.rID = R2.rID) 
    Join Rating Rt2 on (Rt2.rID = R.rID)
 Where Rt.MID = Rt2.mID and R.rID < r2.rID
```

I know I need to have a table with 2 Reviewer Name columns and 2 Movie columns. I apply the condition so that the movies have to equal each other and the condition that the Id's cannot be the same as the question says "*Don't pair reviewers with themselves, and include each pair only once*".

My result is empty (incorrect). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must join the table `rating` twice to the table `movie` and for each join, join the table `reviewer`. 
Then filter the result so that reviewers are not paired with themselves and by using `distinct` and  `min()` and `max()` functions make sure that each pair is not repeated:

```
select distinct
  min(v1.name, v2.name) reviewer1,
  max(v1.name, v2.name) reviewer2
from movie m
inner join rating r1 on r1.mid = m.mid
inner join rating r2 on r2.mid = m.mid
inner join reviewer v1 on v1.rid = r1.rid
inner join reviewer v2 on v2.rid = r2.rid
where v1.rid <> v2.rid
order by reviewer1, reviewer2
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why joining rating on mID not rID makes a big difference logically?

Comment: You must start with the table `movie` and then proceed to `rating` (twice) by `mid` of course since this is the link between them and for each of the `rating` joins make one join to `reviewer`. This is the logical path.

Answer (score 6):

I would start with the self join on rating and then bring in the names:

```
select distinct rv1.name, rv2.name
from rating r1 join
     rating r2
     on r1.mid = r2.mid join
     reviewer rv1
     on rv1.rid = r1.rid join
     reviewer rv2
     on rv2.rid = r2.rid and rv1.name < rv2.name;
```

Your query is actually very similar. I think the main issue is the `select distinct` and the ordering by name instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(NAME),MAX(NAME) 
FROM (SELECT MID,NAME 
      FROM RATING R,REVIEWER R1 
      WHERE R.RID=R1.RID 
      GROUP BY MID,R.RID 
      ORDER BY MID,NAME)
GROUP BY MID 
ORDER BY MIN(NAME)
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question "What am I doing wrong" and it doesn't "explain" it either.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Answer**

```
select distinct rv1.name,rv2.name
from rating r1 
join rating r2 on r1.mid = r2.mid 
join reviewer rv1 on rv1.rID= r1.rID 
join reviewer rv2 on rv2.rID = r2.rID and rv1.name < rv2.name
order by rv1.name,rv2.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
select rev1.*, rev2.*
from Rating rat1
JOIN Rating rat2 on rat2.mID = rat2.mID AND rat1.rID < rat2.rID
JOIN Reviers rev1 ON rev1.rID = rat1.rID
JOIN Reviers rev2 ON rev2.rID = rat2.rID
order by rev1.name, rev2.name
```

Distinct is always good to be avoided.
And it's always good join tables using ids, and after that, order using some criteria, like name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rev.name, rev2.name
FROM ( SELECT distinct rID, mID
       FROM   RATING  as r )          as t1
INNER JOIN (  SELECT distinct rID, mID
              FROM   RATING  as r )   as t2    On t1.MID = t2.MID
INNER JOIN Reviewer  as rev   ON t1.RID = rev.RID
INNER JOIN Reviewer  as rev2  ON t2.RID = rev2.RID
WHERE t1.RID <> t2.RID
  AND t1.RID < t2.RID 
GROUP by rev.name, rev2.name
ORDER by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct Min(name) as Mn, Max(name) as Mx 
From Rating Join Reviewer Using(rID)
Group by mID
Order by Mn
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select r1.name n1, r2.name n2 from (
    select distinct a1.rid rid1, a2.rid rid2 from rating a1 inner join rating a2 on a1.mid = a2.mid 
    and not a1.rid = a2.rid
)r 
inner join reviewer r1 on r.rid1 = r1.rid
inner join reviewer r2 on r.rid2 = r2.rid
where r1.name < r2.name order by r1.name
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question "What am I doing wrong" and it doesn't "explain" it either.

Answer (score -1):

```
select DISTINCT min(name) as rv1, max(name) rv2
from Rating r1, Reviewer
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) from Rating r2 WHERE r1.mID = r2.mID) > 1 and r1.rID = Reviewer.rID
GROUP by r1.mID
ORDER by rv1
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question "What am I doing wrong" and it doesn't "explain" it either.